# Loop through files in make file

Tags: makefile, wildcard

Right now I have the following in my make file to create a symbolic link to a file in my current directory:

```
MY_FILE := "$(SOME_PATH)/file.txt"

ln -s $(MY_FILE)
```

What I would like is to do some sort of glob operation to link a bunch of files (or none).

```
MY_FILES :=  "$(SOME_PATH)/*.txt"
for file in files:
   ln -s $(MY_FILE)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to make a lot of symbolic links during the build process?  Wouldn't it be run as an environment setup type thing?  Then why don't you keep a shell/batch file to create these symlinks?

Comment: Right now I need to copy a lot of data into my current working directory everytime. I'd like to have it just make symbolic links on compile-time, so I don't have to do this everytime. I suppose it could be an enviroment setup, but with other files we use symbolic links so I'd rather keep the workflow the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
MY_FILES := $(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*.txt)
LINKS    := $(notdir $(MY_FILES))

.PHONY: links clean-links
links: $(LINKS)

$(LINKS): %: $(SOME_PATH)/%
    ln -s $<

clean-links:
    rm -f $(LINKS)
```

Explanation:

1. Make functions. `wildcard` and `notdir` are two [make functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Functions). Knowing the make functions (at least the most frequently used) really helps writing nice, elegant and efficient make files. Of course, if you have spaces or special characters in your file names you will encounter some problems because most make functions consider spaces as separators. But if you have such files and directory names you should probably use something else than make.
2. Static pattern rules:

   ```
   $(LINKS): %: $(SOME_PATH)/%
   ```

   is a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). For each word `foo.txt` in `$(LINKS)` it instantiates one single make rule:

   ```
   foo.txt: $(SOME_PATH)/foo.txt
       ln -s $(SOME_PATH)/foo.txt
   ```

   Knowing how to use pattern rules (static or not) is essential if you want to write compact and generic make files.
3. Automatic variables. `$<` is a make [automatic variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables). In recipes (the commands part of rules) it expands as the first listed pre-requisite. There are many other automatic variables and they are quite handy to write generic rules.
4. Phony targets. `links` and `clean-links` are [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) because they do not correspond to real files that we want make to create or update. They are kind of short-hands for actions. `make links` creates all missing links and `make clean-links` removes them all. As make has no way to guess that these targets are not regular file names we tell it with the `.PHONY` special target.

Comment: +1 on static rules. Had hard time understanding how to use them in practice but reading this it makes sense :-). PHONY targets are always rebuilt, which is useful for actions since they would stop working (be considered up-to-date and skipped) should there be a file or folder named the same as the command.

Comment: Could `links: | $(LINKS)` save us the work of renewing already existing links? Or do I overlook something?

Comment: @Vroomfondel: By default make considers the last modification time of the target of symbolic links, not the last modification time of the links themselves. So, in a `link-to-file: file` rule, if `link-to-file` and `file` exist, they will have the same modification times and make will not renew the link. It will be up-to-date by construction.

Answer (score 0):

Make creates "targets" from "prerequisites". In your case `MY_FILES` holds prerequisites to create the (link) targets. The rule for a single file might look like this:

```
file.txt: $(SOME_PATH)/file.txt
    ln -s $<
```

You want multiple files, and in this case we can use this pattern rule:

```
%.txt: $(SOME_PATH)/%.txt
    ln -s $<
```

You can now create links with the make commands:

```
make file.txt
make otherfile.txt
```

Finally we will look into the `wildcard` function to get all files, and the function `notdir` function to get the link names from the file names. Following rule will print all text files, and depends on all files in SOME_PATH linked to current working directory:

```
MY_FILES := $(notdir $(wildcard $(SOME_PATH)/*.txt))
cat: $(MY_FILES)
    cat $^

%.txt: $(SOME_PATH)/%.txt
    ln -s $<
```